# Cordova app external links not working on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, web, view, cordova-plugins

I have a Cordova app (built with PGB) where external link stopped working on iOS. The links work fine on Android and as a WebApp, just not iOS. I tried both UIWebView and WkWebView. This used to work fine on all platforms. I'm not sure when it broke (Cordova 6 or iOS 11). I use the whitelist plugin with:

```
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

The CORS header is:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="default-src 'self' gap://ready file://* *;
    style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
    script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';"
>
```

The links are all external. I don't need or want them in the app WebView. I'd prefer a separate instance of Safari. Do I need to use the inappbrowser plugin anyway?

Answer (score 5):

`allow-navigation` takes precedence over `allow-intent`, you will have to remove the `allow-navigation` entry or change it to only allow navigation to certain urls, not all.

Comment: Correct, after removing `allow-navigation` from config file, iOS does opens links in browser.
But do you know how I can make it work if I want to embed ToyTube videos using `<allow-navigation href="https://*youtube.com/*" />`? 
No matter what I do, I can make only one (links or embedded video) to work. But I want both to be working at same time.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me! Defining `allow-navigation` to allow embeds will break external links so to fix this, I had to install inAppBrowser plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser and used js to open the links with `cordova.InAppBrowser.open(href, '_system');`